# Visual artifact on fltk-1.3.5 widget

Tags: c++, fltk

I'm currently working on a tic tac toe game and I cannot figure out how to remove the visual artifact (enlarged arrow in the Fl_Choice/Dropdown) that you can see in the image. You can find the code at https://github.com/FG-33/TicTacToeML.

I'm working on windows using fltk-1.3.5.

[image: 1]]
.

Currently I have two types of components which I'm using to create the GUI. The first one being a shape that is drawn using fltk's draw methods:

```
class GameWindow : Fl_Double_Window { 
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IShape>> shapes;
    void draw() override;

..

void GameWindow::draw() {
    Fl_Double_Window::draw();
    for(int i=0;i<shapes.size();i++)
        shapes[i]->draw();
}

void Line::draw() const { // An example for an IShape
    fl_color(FL_FOREGROUND_COLOR);
    fl_line_style(FL_SOLID, line_width); // has to be after color on win32
    fl_line(lineStart.x(), lineStart.y(), lineEnd.x(), lineEnd.y());
}
```

To break it down there is this class GameWindow that contains a vector which holds all the shapes I want to draw. The class overrides `Fl_Double_Window`'s draw method.

The second type of GUI components are the actual ones given by fltk:

```
class ConfigDialog : public IWidget {
    std::shared_ptr<Fl_Box> box;
    void attach() override;

..

void ConfigDialog::attach() {
    box = std::make_shared<Fl_Box>(FL_SHADOW_BOX, topLeft.x(), topLeft.y(), width, height, ""); 
}

void GameWindow::attach(std::shared_ptr<IWidget> w) {
        begin();
        w->attach();
        end();
        widgets.push_back(w); // there's also a vector for widgets
}
```

To create the widgets I'm calling the `attach()` methods which initializes the fltk widgets from the window class. To remove the widgets and shapes I call the vector's `clear()`-methode.

What I'm doing and when the artifact occurs:

```
// start the game in main

// Create dialog in the image // THE ERROR DOES NOT OCCUR HERE
view.attach(move(make_shared<ConfigDialog>(ConfigDialog(Point(width/6, height/3), width*2/3, height/3+height/40, this))));

// Remove the dialog if game is started
widgets.clear()

// add some shapes and draw them like this
fl_color(FL_FOREGROUND_COLOR);
fl_line_style(FL_SOLID, line_width); // has to be after color on win32
fl_line(lineStart.x(), lineStart.y(), lineEnd.x(), lineEnd.y());

// remove the shapes if game is finished
shapes.clear()

// add config dialog in the image again // NOW THE ERROR OCCURS
view.attach(move(make_shared<ConfigDialog>(ConfigDialog(Point(width/6, height/3), width*2/3, height/3+height/40, this))));
```

Any help, tips or pointers on what might be the case of the artifact are appreciated.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what exactly you are calling the artifact. The only oddity looks like the oversized down-arrow used for the list-box drop-down. Is that what you are talking about? If so, that seems more like a sizing issue rather than an artifact.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the suggestion, I did edit the question. You might be correct. Before adding the dialog I'm drawing multiple lines with line width ~6, which could influence the drawing of the dialog/arrows.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried running the project on linux and there's much more happening there. As a result I'm sure the artifact most certainly occurs because of the thicker line width of the components that I'm drawing before adding the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

How I draw different kinds of shapes:

```
void Line::draw() const {
    fl_color(FL_FOREGROUND_COLOR);
    fl_line_style(FL_SOLID, line_width); // has to be after color on win32
    fl_line(lineStart.x(), lineStart.y(), lineEnd.x(), lineEnd.y());
}
```

The proplem is that `fl_line_style(FL_SOLID, line_width);` can still change the line width of other things added to the window afterwards. So in order to solve this I did reset the line width to 1 by adding

```
fl_line_style(FL_SOLID, 1);
```

at the end of the draw function.